# Firebase cloud functions : Delete multiple documents on userDelete

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I would like to be able to delete all of a user's documents when deleting his account. I would like to do this on the backend side with cloud functions.
[This similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49515063/delete-multiple-documents-with-firebase-cloud-function) doesn't really answer my question (because I need to delete documents from multiple collections)

Here is the structure of my collections:

```
users 
  | uid
      | email: userEmail@test.com


orders 
  | docId
      | createdBy: uid
      | …
      | …
```

Here is my function:

```
const userDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(user => {
  // get user doc in users collection then remove it
  const usersRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
  usersRef.delete();
  
  // get all user’s doc in orders collection
  const ordersRef = db.collection("orders")
    .where("createdBy", "==", user.uid)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        ordersRef.doc(doc.id).delete();
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Error getting documents", err);
    });

  return Promise.all(usersRef, ordersRef);
})
```

I need to iterate through the orders collection and find the documents that have the correct uid in the "createdBy" property and then delete them. I feel like I can't delete multiple things at once during onDelete, and I couldn't find anything concrete in the documentation.

Firebase logs return to me this error : `object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Function.all` when deleting a user.
The problem occurs on the following line: `return Promise.all(ordersRef);`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem you encounter when you run this code? Is there an error message?

Comment: Firebase logs return to me this error :  `object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at Function.all` when deleting a user.

Comment: Hmm... I don't immediately see what line that'd come from. Can you determine which line in your code cause that error?

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs on the following line: `return Promise.all(ordersRef);`
So there must be some problem in the javascript logic. I'm relatively new, I think I'm using promises badly.

Comment: Wow, that took me a moment to spot, but it's really just a syntax error. Answer below

Answer (score 0):

`Promise.all` expects an array of promises, so you need to put `[]` around the arguments:

```
return Promise.all([usersRef, ordersRef]);
```